# Discord.py Button responses interaction failed after 3 min

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The button doesn't respond if no one has clicked it in 3 minutes.
I saw that it was something with timeout but I don't know where to place it.

My code:

```
#Tickets
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label=" Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
    async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        with open("open_channels_user_id.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            user_id = data["user_id"]

            if user_id != interaction.user.id:
                admin_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="hulpje")
                category = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, name='Ticket')
                overwrites = {interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                              interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                              interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                              admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
                new_ticket = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket- {interaction.user.name}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
                channel = client.get_channel(new_ticket.id)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Ticket- {interaction.user.name}', description="Goed dat je een ticket opent. \n Stuur alvast wat informatie zodat het makkelijker is voor het staff team.", color=0x004BFF)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"Ticket is geopen met de naam: Ticket- {interaction.user.name}")

                data['user_id'] = interaction.user.id
                with open("open_channels_user_id.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)

                time.sleep(3)
                await interaction.channel.purge(limit=1)

            else:
                await interaction.channel.send("Je hebt al een ticket openstaan.")
                time.sleep(5)
                await interaction.channel.purge(limit=1)

async def menu(ctx):
    view = Menu()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Ticket", description="Vragen, klachten of iets anders maak hier je Ticket aan en wordt zo snel mogelijk geholpen!", color=0x004BFF)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

I don't know what to do. Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the timeout value like this:

```py
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=180) # Timeout value in seconds
        self.value = None
```

If you set it to `None`, it will never time out, until you restart your bot.
If you want the view to persist between bot restarts, see this example here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py